# Need to Stream Live Video and Audio on my Website from somewhere like OBS

Tags: streaming, html5-video

We are looking at using OBS on our website to stream live video of our customer service agents and use chat in conjunction with it. We want to use OBS because we can show customers how to navigate our site, we can also show product comparisons, etc. The problem with most standard chat services is that they drown out the background noise and that totally defeats the purpose of what we are trying to accomplish with the product comparisons. Does anybody have any idea on where to even start on this?

Answer (score 2):

I have written a tutorial for this purpose on the OBS forum : [How to set up your own private RTMFP server using MonaServer](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/how-to-set-up-your-own-private-rtmfp-server-using-monaserver.153/).

It uses [MonaServer](http://monaserver.ovh), an open source web communication server that you can use as media server in your case.

I have also built two simple chat clients, one in websocket, the other in flash, take a look at our samples here : http://www.monaserver.ovh/samples.html

I hope it will help you. Ask me if you need more informations.

Answer (score 0):

On server side, you have to think about to manage a server streaming,
to think about the ressources hardwares, the language code.

Actionscript II or III with actionscript server side (asc) for FMS and for RED5 Wowza Java.

server streaming
open source server
Red5
https://code.google.com/p/red5/

pay server
Wowza
http://www.wowza.com/
FMS (Flash Media Server) 
Adobe